# Git pulled from one branch, edited, now push on a different branch

Tags: git, version-control

Good day all.
I've pulled the master branch of a project, edited it but now I'd like to push this edits to a brand new branch (and also switch to that branch).

to be clear, now I'm on:
master

I'd like to push on a new remote branch, called "investment" (that doesn't exist at this time) and switch on that branch, so later doing a git status it should appear like:

master

investment*

I don't want to push these edits on the master, that branch must remain clean as was in the moment I have pulled.

is that possible, or I have to clone back everything, change the branch, redo the mods and push?

EDIT:

What happens is that I pulled the master, then start to edit, but what I intended to do was to first switch on a new branch THEN edit. Now I'd like to preserv all those modification into a new branch AND have the original (pre modification) master.

Comment: By 'a brand new branch', do you mean that this branch does not share any history with master?

Comment: I mean that this investment branch is new both locally and remotely.
it is not present anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way for you to transfer the modification from master branch to investment branch by below steps:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b investment
git branch -D master
git push origin investment
```

You will find the structure is what you want. If you need to modify master branch, just use `git checkout master`.

Answer (score 0):

> I've pulled the master branch of a project, edited it but now I'd like to push this edits to a brand new branch (and also switch to that branch).

1. create a branch and switch to it `git checkout -b investment`
2. If the branch should be a remote branch use after checkout `git push -u origin investment`
3. commit and push your changes

If you mean something else, you have to give us more details about your problem/question.

Comment: so with git "checkout -b " what happens is that everything I see in the project goes into the new branch, and switching back to the master I should see the original (pre modification) master?

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straightforward. Here are the steps:

1. Checkout master to local: `git checkout master`
2. Create new branch on local: `git checkout -b investment`

Now, you will be on branch `investment` and it will be exactly the same as the master branch that you had cloned earlier.

Then, make any changes you want in this `investment` branch.

3. Lets add and commit the changes you made locally on investment branch:

`git commit -a -m "Commit message"`

4. Finally push your changes to remote branch: `git push origin investment`

Your `master` branch is untouched and in the same state you had initially cloned, and, your new changes are in the `investment` branch.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already done some changes on the "master" code, and now I'd like to push those changes on a new branch, without waste the master one, I know I shold have changed the branch earlyer, but... that's life :D

Comment: If there are not too many changes and you can easily implement them on a new branch, you could just reset the master branch: `git reset --hard HEAD` and start fresh. Maybe create a test branch with your changes before you reset master as that will totally erase whatever changes you had made on master.